# How can I use JavaScript to match a string inside the current URL of the window I am in?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have used the excellent gskinner.com/RegExr/ tool to test my string matching regex but I cannot figure out how to implement this into my JavaScript file to return true or false.

The code I have is as follows:

```
^(http:)\/\/(.+\.)?(stackoverflow)\.
```

on a url such as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` this would match (according to RegExr) `http://stackoverflow.`

So this is great because I want to try matching the current `window.location` to that string, but the issue I am having is that this JavaScript script does not work:

```
var url = window.location;
if ( url.match( /^(http:)\/\/(.+\.)?(stackoverflow)\./ ) ) 
{
    alert('this works');
};
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks for reading.

Jannis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test domain name (host) `window.location.host` gives you what you need (with subdomain)

```
if( /^(.*\.)?stackoverflow\./.test(window.location.host) ){
    alert('this works');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`window.location` is not a string; it's an object. Use `window.location.href`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I couldn't quite get this to work so i went with Pawel's solution, but thanks again nonetheless.

Comment: This is good answer, too. window.location is an object, .href nad .host are its properties represented as strings. You can use any of these, but I thought location.host is better when you're only interested in this part of location string :)

Comment: ah, now it makes sense to me, so the href will return the full url whereas the host will only go as far as `http://sub.domain.ext/` ?

Comment: Host will only return the "sub.domain.ext" part, as that is the host.