# If condition for redirection in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Edit...

Someone suggested I do it differently...  If I were to use .htaccess, would this work?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^chapter http://mysite.com/chapter/1
```

I'm just using basic javascript here, but I wanted to find out if there's a way to add it to my jquery file so that the redirection will happen if the path matches something specific?

Right now, I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace("/chapter/1");</script>
```

I'd like that to *only* occur if the user goes to http://mysite.com/chapter.

I'm not altogether clear on how to get the path using jquery and do a pattern match?

Comment: I believe this would be better suited using mod_rewrite as part of apache if you have access to this aspect of your service environment.  


Can you provide more details on the desired result? I am not totally clear which is why I think you want mod_rewrite not client side scripting for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is a Javascript *library* which helps you manipulate DOM elements.
Since you're not manipulating DOM elements, jQuery won't do you any good.

You can use the `location.href` property:

```
if (location.href === '...')
    location.replace("/chapter/1");
```

Or,

```
if (/regex pattern/.test(location.href))
    location.replace("/chapter/1");
```

However, you should probably do this on the server instead.

Comment: I see.  You mean, just using like an .htaccess file? In which case, would the edit in my original post work?

Comment: I did, but I quickly realized it won't exactly work...  The "1" is dynamic, and I'm not sure how to pass that to an .htaccess file.  Essentially, the "1" represents an ID.  So, if a user goes to /chapter, they should be redirected to /chapter/[ID]...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if(window.location.href.match(/^.*\/chapter\/?$/)){
    window.location.replace("/chapter/1");
  }

});
```

See this question: [How can I use JavaScript to match a string inside the current URL of the window I am in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522532/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-match-a-string-inside-the-current-url-of-the-window-i)

You can use the same regex in the htaccess file...